# Keeping history of widget changes?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to keep a history of changes that have been made to widgets (say, HTML/Text widgets) and revert back to earlier versions if necessary?

There doesn't seem to be such a feature natively, and I haven't been able to find a plugin that adds those capabilities either.

Comment: Not that I know of, but it would probably be relatively simple to write a crude plugin to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to do so is to move the widget into the "Inactive Widget" section.  It will keep their settings, text, html, etc.

Of course, you have to manually duplicate the contents back into the "Active Widgets" section - but that's not too hard.

So, yes, it's possible - but it's hardly a robust versioning system :-)

Comment: So you would basically move the current version to "Inactive Widgets" as a backup, before editing a copy?

Comment: Yeah, not a brilliant solution if you're constantly editing widget, but it does work.  You can keep multiple backups in the "Inactive Widgets" pile.

Comment: Not brilliant, but better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: The Widget Revisions plugin will solve your problem. Here you can find it at: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-revisions/